# socket.io data from server to client

Tags: socket.io

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...');

client.on('join', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    io.emit('messages', 'Hello');

});

});
```

index.html

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:7777');
    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
      socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');

    });
    socket.on('messages', function(data) {
      alert(data);
    });
</script>
```

I tried to implement very basic of Socket.io.

However, data sending from client to server is available but from server to client doesn't work.

In the command running server.js, 'Hello World from client' is printed. However, alert window doesn't work in the web browser.(I've also tried to console.log).

How to solve this?

**Editted**

I've put server.js codes in the app.get('/', function(req, res)){ ... }
Then, it doesn't work. Why it doesn't work in app.get?

Comment: socket.io code does not belong in a specific route.  If you can explain what you're trying to do with the `app.get()` part of your question and you can show us what code you put inside of `app.get()` then perhaps we could offer a suggestion.  But, right now that part of your question is really vague and unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to retrieve data from elasticsearch using node.js and send it to the front. I found that several solutions to deal with it are using ejs or pug. I've tried to use template with pug and vue.js but what I want to do (combining with google map api) is not working well. That's why I choose socket.io. Also, I thought it would be better to send data from server to front when I enter the specific url like app.get('/test',...).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I hope it works:

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
console.log('Client connected...');

client.on('join', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        io.emit('join', data);  //this code sending data from server to client
    });
});
```

Comment: What a shame! Thanks mate. I mixed these codes with others so I missed that code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to fetch some data with an Ajax call such as `/test`, then there is no need to use socket.io.  That's just a classic request/response.

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    // collect your data and then send it as a response
    res.json(data);
});
```

If you're just trying to incorporate data into a web page that is requested, then you can use `res.render()` with the template engine of your choice (ejs, handlebars, pug, etc...).  That would typically look like this:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    // collect your data and then pass it to res.render() to render your
    // your template using that data
    res.render('someTemplateName', data);
});
```

The main thing that socket.io is useful for is "pushing" data from server to client without a client request.  So, if something happened on the server that the client was not aware of and the server wanted to tell the client about it, then socket.io would be used for that.  The classic example is a chat app.  Person A sends a chat message to the server that is addressed to Person B.  The server receives that message and then needs to "push" it to Person B.  That would be perfect for an already connected socket.io connection because the server can just push the data directly to the Person B client, something the server can't do with request/response (since there is no request from person B).

---

If you still think you need socket.io, then please describe exactly what you're trying to do with it (step by step what you're trying to send to the client).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've found solutions using template engines like yours. However, the reason why I use socket.io is that I was confused how to merge template engine and google map api. For example, if data in `res.render('someTemplateName, data);` is a bunch of coordinates, I want to make heatmap by using these coordinates. In this case, is it possible to merge template engine and google map api?

Comment: @coffeedjason - You collect data from Google maps API and put it in a desired format for your template, then pass it to `res.render()`.  I still don't see how socket.io has anything to do with a solution here unless you somehow need live push from server to client when there is no client request underway.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. My explanation is not good I think. What I want to do is retrieving data (coordinates) from database and expressing these coordinates in the front with google map api. For that, I want to pass the array of json (coordinates) to the front and unpack this array in the front to represent each coordinate. For this, if I use `res.render()`, I need to render the html file with template engine in the server-side in my understanding. In this stage, is it possible to render the html file with such api like google maps?

Comment: @coffeedjason - You can "render" the data into a Javascript array in a script tag and the your client-side Javascript can use that array with Google Maps to show the data.

Comment: I'm confused about that point. Doesn't `res.render()` require template as the first argument? Is it possible just rendering javascript array with `res.render()`? In my understanding, `res.render()` and template engine are making html file first and send it to the front. Then, do I need to handle javascript array in the template file? Or just send data to the front and client-side javascript handles that data? Sorry for long questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
   socket.on("message",function (reply_data) {
        console.log('inside on message functions ')
        console.log(reply_data);
    })
```

please change 'messages' to "message" that worked for me